# pipe 'number' could not be found

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have an angular app. All is working fine, but when I try to add a **number pipe** to a component I receive this error message:

> product.finalPrice | number:'1.2-2'
>
> The pipe 'number' could not be found

I don't understand what's goind wrong

This happens with BrowserModule added and with CommonModule too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Why am I getting "Pipe not found" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945254/angular2-why-am-i-getting-pipe-not-found-error)

Comment: Did you import `BrowserModule` and `CommonModule` in `app.module.ts`?

Comment: I tried with BrowserModule alone, and with CommonModule,

Comment: imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxDatatableModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],

Comment: Show in the question the full code of the module that contains the component.

Comment: Are you using the pipe in a different module than the one CommonModule was imported in?

Comment: Try restarting ng serve